# Click a button twice to POST

Tags: yii2

this my view file for a signin page

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

    <?= $form->field( $model, 'email' )->textInput( [ 'maxlength' => 200 ], [ 'id' => 'email' ] ) ?>

    <?= $form->field( $model, 'password' )->passwordInput( [ 'maxlength' => 200 ] ) ?>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-14">
            <?= Html::submitButton( 'Login',
                [ 'class' => 'btn btn-danger btn-block btn-lg', 'name' => 'login-button' ] ) ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <input type='sub' name='submit' value='Reset Password' class="btn btn-link btn-default" '>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

it works perfectly but you have to click on the login button twice. there is no other problem in signing in. i don't have a clue why i have to click the login button twice.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly You've got syntax in your `input type='sub'` at the end You've got `'` instead of `/`. You should render it by `Html::input`, then you'll avoid syntax.

Secondly change this input name. `name='submit'` brookes `ActiveForm`. Not sure why...

Comment: You're rirght, Patryk. Don't know why, but it really broke ActiveForm. I got an example somewhere that already has name='submit' and changing it solved the problem completely.

Comment: exactly, just remove `name='submit'`

Answer (score 2):

`name='submit'` is your problem here. Change it to `name='not_submit'` and all will be well.

The post here explains why `name='submit'` causes problems for `ActiveForm`.

[Yii2 form submit button must be clicked two times for action. How to prevent this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38557838/yii2-form-submit-button-must-be-clicked-two-times-for-action-how-to-prevent-thi/43904791#43904791)

Comment: If I change the `button name` its post nothing. $_POST['not_submit'] return nothing in my controller. What could be wrong?