# Yii2 form submit button must be clicked two times for action. How to prevent this?

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

yii2 submit button needs to be clicked two times in form

I have a problem where I need to check more than one submit buttons in the controller. It works but I need to click submit buttons two times. 
 In controller :

```
switch(\Yii::$app->request->post('submit')) {
                case 'submit_1' :

                  //my code 
                   break;  

                case 'submit_2' :                   
                 //my code
```

In view

```
<?= Html::submitButton('NEXT', ['name' => 'submit', 'value' => 'submit_2','class'=>'btn btn-primary pull-right']) ?>
<?= Html::submitButton('PREVIOUS', ['name' => 'submit', 'value' => 'submit_3','id'=>'next_summary', 'class' => 'btn btn-primary pull-right']) ?>
```

Comment: try by changing name of both buttons like submit1 and submit2

Comment: If you want that the button must be clicked twice before doing something, you can use JS or jQuery to change it's name/value to something different and check if it was pressed again.

Comment: changing the names would not show any value in post.Only 'submit' shows the values.

Answer (score 9):

There is an issue with using jquery reserved words as your attribute id or attribute names.

Search for "Be careful when naming form elements such as submit buttons" at
https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/input-forms.md

Search "Additional Notes" at https://api.jquery.com/submit/

Changing your submit names will fix your click twice problem:

```
<?= Html::submitButton('NEXT', ['name' => 'submit_next', 'value' => 'submit_2','class'=>'btn btn-primary pull-right']) ?>
<?= Html::submitButton('PREVIOUS', ['name' => 'submit_prev', 'value' => 'submit_3','id'=>'next_summary', 'class' => 'btn btn-primary pull-right']) ?>
```

Comment: Worked for me after changing `'name' => 'submit_something'`;

Answer (score 0):

try to change name of button as array

```
 <?= Html::submitButton('NEXT', ['name' => 'submit[]', 'value' => 'submit_2','class'=>'btn btn-primary pull-right']) ?>
<?= Html::submitButton('PREVIOUS', ['name' => 'submit[]', 'value' => 'submit_3','id'=>'next_summary', 'class' => 'btn btn-primary pull-right']) ?>
```

and in your controller :

```
$submittedType = \Yii::$app->request->post('submit');
switch($submittedType[0]) {
   //your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid double click disable validate on submit:

```
$form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'validateOnSubmit' => false,
]);
```